# ImportError:No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to learn mnist through tensorflow.
everything work just fine but too slow,
so I follow the tensorflow-gpu installation instructions in tensorflow.org,
but while I import tensorflow it shows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

ImportError: DLL load failed。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

ImportError: DLL load failed。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I using Win10, python3.6, GTX1070
I type "nvcc -V" in cmd shows:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:32_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

and I also run the "deviceQuery" and "bandwidthTest", all show "pass",
I did install "vc_redist.x64" and set system variable as 
"cuDNN Install Guide" says.

```
system variable:
variable name : CUDA_HOME
variable value : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0

variable in PATH:
C:\Program Files\Python36;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0;
```

but still I can't fix this problem, any help would be great.

Comment: As far as I know, Tensorflow currently only supports CUDA Toolkit 8.0 (as specified in the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)).

Comment: thanks! @aseipel I change to 8.0 now, but still same issue.

Comment: oh I got it! I reinstall tensorflow-gpu again and it work! thanks again @aseipel !